# Harvard Architecture maps to HLL

Tags: c++, cpu-architecture, high-level, von-neumann, harvard-architecture

This is a question I have been searching for a while but I have not got a proper answer yet :(

- How does the Harvard Architecture map to C/C++ languages (High Level Languages)?
- How are they related or how does the architecture help HLLs?

Answer (score 2):

The only way Harvard vs Princeton architecture is really relevant to C++ is in the rule 5.2.10p8 concerning mixing function pointers and object pointers:

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined,  except that if an implementation supports conversions in both  directions,  converting  a  prvalue  of  one  type  to  the  other  type  and  back,  possibly  with  different *cv-qualification*, shall yield the original pointer value.

That rule allows C++ to be used on machines which have separate address spaces for code and data.